# Traefik 2.0: How to assign global static IP with IngressRoute (CRD)?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, traefik, traefik-ingress

Following the tutorial for Kubernetes (in my case on GKE) https://docs.traefik.io/v2.0/user-guides/crd-acme/ I am stuck on how to assign the global static IP (GKE wants a forwarding rule). Am I missing something (e.g. adding another ingress)? I understand that annotations are not possible in the IngressRoute. So how would I assign the global reserved IP?

The answer to question 3 on this Q&A online meetup (https://gist.github.com/dduportal/13874113cf5fa1d0901655e3367c31e5) mentions that "classic ingress" is also possible with version 2.x. Does this mean I can set up traefik as in 1.x (like this: https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/kubernetes/) use 2.x configuration and no need for CRD?

Answer (score 2):

You do it like with every other Ingress Controller.

A good step-by-step instructions on how to assign a Static IP address to an Ingress are given on nginx-ingress`s website.

Follow the section called '[Promote ephemeral to static IP](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/static-ip/#promote-ephemeral-to-static-ip)'

If to follow Traefik 2.0's [exemplary](https://github.com/containous/traefik/tree/master/docs/content/user-guides/crd-acme) manifests files made for Kubernetes, once you patch your Traefik's K8S Service (with kubectl patch traefik...), you can verify if IngressRoute's took effect with following command:

```
 curl -i http://<static-ip-address>:8000/notls -H 'Host: your.domain.com'
```

**Update**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: traefik
spec:
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      name: web
      port: 8000
    - protocol: TCP
      name: admin
      port: 8080
    - protocol: TCP
      name: websecure
      port: 4443
  selector:
    app: traefik
  type: LoadBalancer
```

and patch it with:

```
kubectl patch svc traefik -p '{"spec": {"loadBalancerIP": "<your_static_ip>"}}'
```

Comment: Promoting an ephemeral IP to a static one and then assigning it to a load balancer should be the same as assigning an existing static IP to a load balancer (I have a global static one already), right? What I do not understand: to what resource do I assign it? The exemplary manifests lead to two services (which have Cluster IPs) and two IngressRoutes. Where is the loadbalancer? Is it another service I have to set up?

Comment: For you first question: Yes (Promoting an ephemeral IP to a static one and then assigning it to a load balancer should be the same as assigning an existing static IP to a load balancer). For your second question (..to what resource do I assign it?): you assign it to 'traefik' Service, with one more extra thing needed, you need to change type from ClusterIP to LoadBalancer IP. For the clarity I will update my answer with modified YAML file.

Comment: I found out the missing piece: For type: LoadBalancer the IP has to be a REGIONAL static IP (https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/configuring-domain-name-static-ip). Only for ingress the GLOBAL static IPs work.